AAM Wordpress Plugin's URL access is isn't working as expected
I'm using the Advanced Access Manager plugin on my WordPress site to manage users and the content they have access to. However, I'm having a weird problem when trying to deny access to a pdf file or restrict it.
I have this url, for example, https://XXX.XXX/wp-content/uploads/2077/99/File-Z.Z.Z-78-3333-Fda.pdf, and want to restrict access to it in AAM (see the attached image).
However if I try to access the pdf using that URL I can do so even though it's restricted, but if I write incorrectly the url, changing upper case letter by lower case letter, for example https://XXX.XXX/wp-content/uploads/2077/99/file-Z.Z.Z-78-3333-Fda.pdf (changed F of File to f), it redirects me to the login form which is what's supposed to happen when the URL is written properly, and if I login it says that that URL doesn't exist, which is correct.
But why does it have this strange behaviour? I'm racking my brain to think and I'm unable to find a logical explanation.
Thanks.


Might want to try reaching out to AAM's support team as this is third-party code: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-access-manager/
